# Function Compare. When will it sort

Tags: java, collections, interface, compare

```
class PlayerComparatorByRating implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
       return o1.getRating() - o2.getRating();
    }
}
```

Sorry for this "basic" question, but I don't understand what the compare function does. I mean she compares fields of the an object(in this case) but when will it sort? When the return value is < 0, =0 or >0.

Comment: All your questions are answered, in great details, in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-. Read the documentation. It's as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sort, it *compares*. Then you can sort values based on that comparison.
You should call `Collections.sort` on your collection of players and on your custom comparator, like this:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
players.add(...);
Collections.sort(players, new PlayerComparatorByRating();
```

You will get the players sorted in ascending order.

Comment: "Then you can sort values based on that comparison." In which order ?  How does is sort. Does is sort ascending?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your code, the `compare` function:

> - Returns a **negative integer**, if the first argument `o1` is less than the second argument `o2`
> - Returns **zero**, if the first argument `o1` is equal to the second argument `o2`
> - Returns a **postive integer**, if the first argument `o1` is greater than the second argument `o2`

2. For sorting, you have to explicitly call `Collections.sort()`
   method.

> - If your list contains String elements, It is sorted in Alphabetical order.
> - Classes that implement `Comparable` Interface, provides **Natural Ordering**.

More help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html